# Changing the value based on the number of occurences in MS Excel

Tags: excel-formula

In the following table,

### *Name  |Status*

### Emily |  Rich

### Sam   |  Poor

### Emily |  Rich

### Emma  |  Poor

### Emily |  Poor

Emma  |  Rich

The requirement is, for a particular person, if the count of their status "Rich" is >=2 then change all the status occurrences for that person to "Rich". For others whose status does not satisfy the condition, retain their original values.

For example, in the case of Emily, her status is "Rich" in the first 2 occurrences but the status in the third occurrence is "Poor". I want that to be changed to "Rich" as it satisfies the condition and populate the NEWStatus column with the updated results as shown below.

### *Name  |Status* | *NEWStatus*

### Emily |  Rich   |   Rich

### Sam   |  Poor   |   Poor

### Emily |  Rich   |   Rich

### Emma  |  Poor   |   Poor

### Emily |  Poor   |   Rich

Emma  |  Rich   |   Rich

I tried using countif() function but still not getting the desired results. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Formula should be applied on Row 2 of Column-C (C2 Cell) since first row assumed to be the column headers.

Below formula is written by considering Name in Column-A and Status in Column-B

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"Rich")>=2,"Rich",B2)
```

Drag the formula down.

**One step ahead to avoid 0 result when the Column-B cell value is empty.**

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"Rich")>=2,"Rich",IF(B2="","",B2))
```